# difference between creating a new object of class 'list' and creating an object of other user defined class

Tags: python

It's a basic question.

If we run this code `print(type([1,2,3]))`, we can check that `list` is also the instance(object) of `class 'list'`

In normal cases like below, when creating a new object of the class in python, we write this line of code `myobjectx = MyClass()`,

```
class MyClass:
    myVariable = "ddd"

    def function(self):
        print("Hello, World!")

myobjectx = MyClass()
```

But how when creating a new list(object) of class 'list' we don't need to write a line of code like that?
And create a new list instantly like this: `dd = [1,2,3,4]` .
Or is there anyway I can see how python's `class 'list'` code looks like?

Comment: Python provides special syntax for creating instances of `list` (as well as `tuple`, `dict`, `set`, `str`, and `bytes`) that doesn't involve explicit constructor calls. You can't, however, add your own syntax for new types.

Comment: `[...]` is a literal syntax for lists, just as there are literals for int, float, string, tuple, dict, set, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You absolutely can write a similar line of code to create an empty list (an instance of class `list`):

```
my_list = list()
# my_list = []
```

`my_list = [1, 2, 3]` works because the Python interpreter treats this syntax in a special way: `[1, 2, 3]` means "create a `list` object populated with these values".

Same thing for tuples: these two lines are equivalent ways of creating an empty tuple:

```
my_tuple = tuple()
my_tuple = ()
```

Same thing with dictionaries:

```
my_dict = dict()
my_dict = {}
```

Same thing with strings:

```
my_string = str()
my_string = ''
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, is there any way I can see how python's class 'list' code looks like?

Comment: It's provided by your implementation. There is no Python code that creates a list. (For example, in the reference CPython implementation, the `list` class is defined entirely by code written in C.)

Comment: @Seungjun, CPython implements `list()` here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f32c7950e0077b6d9a8e217c2796fc582f18ca08/Objects/listobject.c#L2697. Other implementations of Python can have wildly varying implementations of `list`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with lists too:

```
mylist = list()
print(type(mylist))
# <class 'list'>
```

`list` *is* a class, and calling `list()` is literally calling the class constructor. If you want, you can pass an iterable as an argument, and it will build the list from the elements of that iterable.

However, python allows "list literals" (along with tuple literals, set literals, and dict literals), which allow you to create a pre-built list with a certain set of elements. This is the same as with numbers and strings, which you can also give as literals instead of using their constructors:

```
print(str())
# empty string
print(int())
# 0
```